# PHP - huge array and looping statement

Tags: php, arrays, email, loops, sendgrid

I have an old customer email list (about 1100 emails) and I would like to email them all.
This list is in a gigantic php array.

I am using sendgrid and they have a nice php howto located here: http://sendgrid.com/documentation/display/api/SMTPPHPExample

I am using their code and in one section they have:

```
$toList = array('destination1@example.com', 'destination2@example.com');
```

Now, to not overflow sendgrids servers or get caught in spam filters I would like to only send batches of 100 emails at a time, how can I grab 100 emails from my big array, put them into this array, run through the sendgrid login, send email, then go back, grab the next 100 and run the loop again.

I'm not too php savvy so i have no idea how to set up this loop.

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: I am pretty sure SendGrid has this type of import and throttling build into their service. Why are you *doing it yourself*?

Comment: it its only 1000, why not loop it from 1 to 1000?

Comment: Don't use a `To:` for this, or even a `CC:`. I'm sure your customers will NOT appreciate their email address appearing in everyone ELSE's email. Use a `BCC:` instead to cloak everyone's address, if you must send in batches. Otherwise, send only one email per recipient.

Comment: The list is actually about 1100 people (just edited the original question), also sendgrid wants you to break the lines at 1000 characters, so i'm guessing sticking all 1000 emails will break that. 

Marc, do you know how to change it to BCC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're talking about [`array array_chunk ( array $input , int $size[, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). It splits an array into and array of smaller arrays based off of the value in $size.

Answer (score 2):

```
> Now, to not overflow sendgrids servers
> or get caught in spam filters I would
> like to only send batches of 100
> emails at a time, how can I grab 100
> emails from my big array, put them
> into this array, run through the
> sendgrid login, send email, then go
> back, grab the next 100 and run the
> loop again.
```

Like other users said in the comments I don't think you should worry about overflowing sendgrid because they are sending the emails using a message queue or something not to kill there server because you are not the only user that is using sendgrid. According to the Sendgrid website they have some very big sites like Slideshare/Hootsuite/Get Satisfaction/FourSquare that sent a lot of emails.

---

In the comments you said:

```
> The list is actually about 1100 people
> (just edited the original question),
> also sendgrid wants you to break the
> lines at 1000 characters, so i'm
> guessing sticking all 1000 emails will
> break that. Marc, do you know how to
> change it to BCC?
```

According to [smtp best practices](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/display/api/SMTP):

> You must ensure that the header is
>   folded to line lengths under 1,000
>   characters. Failure to do this can
>   cause intermediate MTA's to split the
>   header for you on non-space
>   boundaries, which will cause spaces to
>   be inserted in the final resulting
>   e-mail.

I assume the PHP libraries does that for you automically and you don't have to even worry about that. If you worry about that you should sent `support@sendgrid.com` an email to ask about that :)??

---

But if you really want to split you should read [cwallenpoole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500818/php-huge-array-and-looping-statement/6500836#6500836) which I think is pretty good. But after splitting the array you should also [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) then to throttle.